# Shoulda and before_ callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, shoulda

I have simple model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :board_id}
  validates :board, presence: true
  validates :display_order, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :board_id}

  before_save :set_display_order

  private

  def set_display_order
    last = self.board.categories.order("display_order DESC").last
    self.display_order = last.display_order + 100 if last
  end
end
```

When I added this before_save callback, these tests start to fail:

```
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:display_order).scoped_to(:board_id) }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:board_id) }
```

With error (this if for the line in private method `last = ...`):

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `categories' for nil:NilClass
```

Other shoulda tests work fine:

```
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:board) }
  it { should belong_to :board }
```

Any idea what is problem here? I tried to change `before_save` to `before_validation` but still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Because shoulda creates record in DB. Gem creates record skipping validations

http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveModel#validate_uniqueness_of-instance_method
`Ensures that the model is invalid if the given attribute is not unique. It uses the first existing record or creates a new one if no record exists in the database. It simply uses ':validate => false' to get around validations, so it will probably fail if there are 'NOT NULL' constraints. In that case, you must create a record before calling 'validate_uniqueness_of'.`

In your case created `category` is empty it means `category.board # => nil` and you call method `categories` from nil.

You should create a record yourself for tests on uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

One way around this limitation of shoulda_matchers and AR callbacks is to redefine the subject of the test which shoulda matchers uses.

example:

```
# category_spec.rb

# assuming you're using factorygirl and have this setup correctly
let(:board) { FactoryGirl.create(:board, :with_many_categories) }
subject { FactoryGirl.build(:category, board: board) }

# your shoulda matcher validations here
```